# How to use two different arrays in same url?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, url

I want to use 3 arrays in same url like this:

> localhost:3001/:Region/:Type/:noofitems/:Locality/:pagenumber/url?:categoryarray/url?:acarray/url?:feesarray

but in nodejs this url is equivalent to

> /:Region/:Type/:noofitems/:Locality/:pagenumber/url?:categoryarray

So, I want to figure out a way of separating url?:categoryarray and url?:acarray so that "url?:acarray" is not included in categoryarray

Answer (score 0):

In a URL you can set "GET" variables using `?var=value`but here only for the first variable for more you have to use:

`?name=value&other=another_value`

Then try this method:

`localhost:3001/:Region/:Type/:noofitems/:Locality/:pagenumber/url?:categoryarray&:acarray&:feesarray`

It will maybe do the job for what you want

Comment: I have tried this process,but still it is not working.It is still showing NOT FOUND(404) that is it is not matching with url enquired and the url on the backend server code